# How to disable scroll in command prompt in windows and go back to write mode

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I enabled scroll option in command prompt and was able to use arrow keys to scroll up and down. Now i want to disable it and enter back to Insert mode so that i can run commands and upward arrow key repeats the last command executed.

How to do that.

Comment: This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions. You're looking for [su] instead. The [help] has more information about the types of questions that are appropriate to ask here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply press enter and it will let you type again.